# Can't compare SQL powershell property to string

Tags: powershell-2.0

I first want to say that I am just learning powershell and this might be a very simple answer, but I have done some research and can't find the exact thing I am looking for.

My Goal:
I am using the SQL cmdlets to try and exclude some databases that we need to run scripts on. Below is my code to get the databases

```
    $ExcludeDBs=Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $EDDSServer -Database EDDS -InputFile $InactiveCaseSQLPath
```

This works fine, it is after this when I am trying to use a foreach loop and try to compare the properties so I can determine which SQL cluster it is on. Below is my code:

```
    $str="__SQL Cluster 13  (ALL NEW CASES HERE)"
    $ExcludeDbs | foreach{
    if($ExcludeDBs | Where-Object SQLclusterName  -eq $str){
    $SQLClusterName="ClusterNameSQL"}
    }#end foreach loop
```

I get the following error:

*Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "SQLclusterName" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Autom
ation.ScriptBlock".*

I think this has something to do with type casting, but I am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLClustername` is being handled as a string - is it a field being returned from your query?

Also, you shouldn't need the `where-object` inside the `foreach`

```
$str="__SQL Cluster 13  (ALL NEW CASES HERE)"
$ExcludeDbs | foreach{
if($_.SQLclusterName  -eq $str){
    $SQLClusterName="ClusterNameSQL"}
}#end foreach loop
```

Comment: Yes SQLClustername is field being returned by the query.